# Prevent Url Rewrite rule for specific page

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config, iis-7.5

I have a IIS url rewrite rule in my website and I want to stop it for specific url to preappend **www.**

My current rule is:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
      <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example\.com$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^static\.example\.com$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Notice: my page url is **http://example.com/chat?id=1&from=/somepage.aspx** (have 2 query string id and from)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a rule at top for exceptional URLs and change action to NoAction. Then stop execution and skip all the rest.

[See this blog post for more details.](https://blog.lextudio.com/2014/11/iis-url-rewrite-tip-break-free)

Comment: @ImranShams Attached a blog post.